# Google Maps API not working in Rails once Coffeescript is compiled for Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript

Running into a bit of a headache with some Coffeescript and/or Rails behaviour.  Everything works fine when run in development (non-compiled JS) but once I pushed to production I started getting:

`Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`

Here's the coffeescript I am using (stripped down to basics):

```
jQuery ->

  @map = null

  new googleMap()

  class googleMap
    window.initMap = ->
      @map = new (google.maps.Map)(document.getElementById('map-overlay'))
```

And it is being called as per the Google Maps API V3 documentation with the follow script loaded at the bottom just below the `</body>` tag on my page.

```
<script async="async" defer="defer" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*snip*&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way the JS is compiled and gets wrapped in an unnamed function but I've spent a bit of time trying to figure it out and am not getting any further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick for using google maps asynconously without globals is to use [jQuery.deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) together with the [Google API loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/).

```
apiLoaded = jQuery.Deferred()
mapInit = jQuery.Deferred()

google.load 'maps', '3',
  other_params: 'sensor=false'
  callback: ->
    apiLoaded.resolve google

apiLoaded.done (google) ->
  mapInit.resolve(
    new (google.maps.map)(document.getElementById('map-overlay'))
  )
  google

mapInit.done (map) ->
  # do something with the map here for example add a marker.
  new (google.maps.Marker)(
    position:
      lat: -25.363
      lng: 131.044
    map: map
    title: 'Hello World!')
  map
```

Comment: I appologize for any errors - I'm not really a coffescript kind of guy.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with my Coffeescript, in the end it turns out bootstrap.min.js inside my vendors folder was breaking it.  Works once that file is removed.